# Updating a target directory with missing files and setting a property aferwards

Tags: java, ant

I have been trying to get the following to work in ant, but have not been able to.

The scenario, I want to be able to set a property to use in a  check based on if any files from a source directory were copied into the target directory.  This should be true for an empty target directory, newer versions of source files, as well as for newer files in the source directory that are not in the target directory.

My prototyping build.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="build01" default="make.obj">
  <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src"/>
  <property name="obj.dir" value="${basedir}/obj"/>
  <fileset id="src.files" dir="${src.dir}"/>

  <target name="make.obj" depends="check.make.obj" unless="make.obj.notneeded">
    <copy todir="${obj.dir}">
      <fileset refid="src.files"/>
    </copy>
    <property name="do.something.else" value="true"/>
  </target>

  <target name="check.make.obj">
  </target>

  <target name="make.final" depends="make.obj" unless="do.something.else">
    <exec executable="mkisofs">
      <arg value="-o"/>
      <arg value="foo.iso"/>
      <arg value="obj"/>
    </exec>
  </target>
</project>
```

My prototype build directory initially looks as follows:

```
.
+ build.xml
+ obj
+ src
  + file01.txt
  + file02.txt
```

After the initial call to ant, I want to see the following:

```
.
+ build.xml
+ foo.iso
+ obj
| + file01.txt
| + file02.txt
+ src
  + file01.txt
  + file02.txt
```

If I run ant again, without making any changes, I do not want ant to update the obj directory or remake foo.iso.

If I update src/file01.txt, src/file02.txt, or add a file (e.g. src/file03.txt), I want ant to update the obj directory, and I want ant to remake foo.iso.

I've tried different  tasks, but I cannot get anything to work right.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
<property name="do.something.else" value="true"/>
```

with this:

```
<uptodate targetfile="foo.iso" property="do.something.else">
    <srcfiles dir="${obj.dir}"/>
</uptodate>
```

[`<uptodate>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) sets a property if the target exists and is newer than the source(s).

Comment: I've tried various <uptodate> tasks, but I've got nothing to work.  I was thinking I could use <uptodate> with a <srcfiles> and <mapper> to check which source files are newer than the equivalent target file, but I could not get that to work.  I know the single targetfile attribute works, but while this example focuses on making an ISO, I have other things I want to do after being able to build the ISO that will have dependencies between the target and source file.  So, really want to use <uptodate> to compare the source with the target.

Comment: Perhaps you can update your question with a more representative example?  I'm thinking [<dependset>](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dependset.html) might help you, but I don't fully understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, the following always returns true

```
  <target name="make.final">
    <echo message="Inside make.final"/>
    <uptodate property="copy.notneeded">
      <srcfiles dir="src" includes="file01.txt"/>
      <mapper type="glob" from="src/*" to="obj/*"/>
    </uptodate>
    <echo message="copy.notneeded=${copy.notneeded}"/>
  </target>
```

It does not matter if the obj directory exists or not, or if all of the files from src already exist in obj.

I've also tried replacing "glob" with "regex"  That does not seem to work either.